# Warning: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: python, mysql, xml

i'm coding parser xml to mysql

the full name of error:

```
1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHA3871376-ABZ-1', '\xd0\x91\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb7\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8\xd1\x87\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd1\x86\xd0\xbe ' at line 1")
```

i have xml file

```
<model>CHA3871376-ABZ-3</model>
```

i think trouble is coding
but i'm trying

```
offer_model = item.getElementsByTagName("model")[0].firstChild.nodeValue.decode('utf-8')
sqlfillOffers = "INSERT INTO offers (offer_id, url, price, currency_id, typePrefix, vendor, model, description) VALUES ('"+str(offer_id) + "', '" + str(offer_url) + "', '" + str(offer_price) + "', '" + str(offer_CurrId) + "', '"+str(offer_typePrefix)+"', '"+str(offer_vendor)+"', '"+str(offer_model)+"', '"+str(offer_description)+"');"
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `print sqlfillOffers` and show the output.

Comment: I dont think you would need a semicolon `;`

Comment: There are few problems with your code; but to start off with, how do you get `offer_description`?

Comment: @thefourtheye: semicolons are only needed when executing sql in a client that supports multiple statements.

Comment: The query you are sending has a `'` character embedded in the last field, which makes a syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do *not* use string interpolation to build your SQL; you'll introduce errors and open yourself up for SQL injection attacks.

Use SQL parameters instead and let the database adapter take care of escaping the values for you:

```
sqlfillOffers = (
    "INSERT INTO offers (offer_id, url, price, currency_id, typePrefix, vendor, model, description) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, )"
)

cursor.execute(
    sqlfilOffers,
    (offer_id, offer_url, offer_price, offer_CurrId, offer_typePrefix, offer_vendor, offer_model, offer_description)
)
```

Comment: This won't solve his actual problem; which is encoding related.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: not if the database connection and database were configured for unicode.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: either way, string interpolation using Unicode values would make matters worse, in which case the answer is *still* to use SQL parameters.